# doe's any one know how to use agoraRTC TokenGenerator in android?

Tags: java, android, access-token, agora.io, videocall

I followed [this documenttation](https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/develop/integrate-token-generation) and applied each instruction correctly. I placed the files in the `/src` folder. but when I tried to import the files it doesn't work correctly as it says.

```
import io.agora.media.RtcTokenBuilder;
import io.agora.media.RtcTokenBuilder.Role;
```

it shows error in `io.agora.media` part. I don't know how to import from the `/src` folder any help?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it !
in the documentation it says to place the folder in `src` of project mode. i have tried but it didn't work. so i placed the `io` directory in normal java package in app mode.

```
 implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11"
```

i have added above library in my project and all works fine